# In Laravel Eloquent, does Model::get() actually fetch the results?

Tags: php, laravel, eloquent

Consider this line:

```
$nodes = Node::orderBy("id", "desc")->take(5)->get()
```

After the execution of the above line, was the Database queried (results were returned)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, it was queried, and you should have the results in `$nodes`.

The `->get()` on the end is what prompts the execution of the query.  Up until that is called, you can continue adding conditions to your query.  The [Advanced Wheres](http://laravel.com/docs/queries#advanced-wheres) section of the Laravel docs has some good examples

Note - If you want to have a look at what's going on, you can always use [`DB::getQueryLog()`](http://laravel.com/docs/database#query-logging)

```
$queries = DB::getQueryLog();
```

Something (very quick and dirty) like this works in a `View`:

```
@foreach(DB::getQueryLog() as $query)
  <pre> {{ print_r($query) }}</pre>
@endforeach
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I wasn't sure whether `get()` actually fetches the result because you can still do things like `$nodes->first()` afterwards.

Comment: aah, yeah ok.  They have implemented `first()` on both the query builder, and the collections you get back from `->get()`. take a look in the API guide - On the collection: http://laravel.com/api/class-Illuminate.Support.Collection.html#_first
 -- and on the DB query builder: http://laravel.com/api/class-Illuminate.Database.Query.Builder.html#_first